# Array of strings returns as one single string with no spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

In my meteor code I return a collection like this

```
Template.posts.helpers({
      posts: function () {
        return Posts.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}});
      }
    });
```

And then render it with blaze into html with help of the

```
{{#each posts}} 
  {{tags}} 
  {{otherstuff}}
{{/each}}
```

But the Posts collection has an tags["one","two","three","four"] array that contains only strings and when i render it on page i get this:

```
one,two,three,four
```

The problem is it inserts commas(don't mind those) and doesn't put spaces between items in array.

Any idea how do I approach this?

Comment: It is because the default toString() method of an array implementation does the concatenation like that.. instead you can try to call the `join()` method of an array with a separator like `array.join(', ')` - not sure how to do it in the meteor template

Answer (score 0):

try iterating the array.  You can wrap each tag with whatever you like

```
{{#each posts}}    
    {{#each tags}}
      <span>{{this}}</span>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of Meteor you are using, but I am assuming that you are using a version of 1.0 or later. In that case, the proper way of implementing a global template helper is like so:

```
    Template.registerHelper('formatArray', function(array) {
        return array.join(', ');
    });
```

Notice the difference of using the `Template` object rather than the `UI` object. Use it like so:

```
    <p>{{formatArray tags}}</p>
```

Comment: I'm using the windows preview version, I think I found somewhere in the examples the UI object being used so i just used that and it worked

Comment: My apologies, I had no idea that the Windows preview version was different from the Mac/Linux version in that regard.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks guys for the help, found out the meteor way to do it.

```
 UI.registerHelper("formatArray", function(array) {

        return array.join(', ')

    });
```

and this

```
<p>{{formatArray tags}}</p>
```

Comment: The "meteor way" would in my opinion be Keith's solution, or simply `{{tags.join ", "}}`.

Comment: Didn't know you could call functions like that in meteor, thanks.